# TextView with background color only on the text itself

Tags: android, textview

How do I implement something like this:

[image]

I want to do that within a single TextView. Setting the background color of the TextView will not do the job.

I guess it should be possible with a spannable, but I don't know how.

In html I would do that:

```
<html>
<body>
        <span style="background:#CCCCCC;">first line <br /> second long line </span>
</body>
</html>
```

But i don't know how to do that on Android.
The very last option would be to split the text into two text view, and set each textviews background color and with/height to wrap_content. But since the text length / count of words can be dynamically, I need to calculate the length of each word etc. There must be a better way :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

something like this should do the job

```
String myString = "first line\nsecond long line";
Spannable spanna = new SpannableString(myString);
spanna.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(0xFFCCCCCC),0, myString.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);           
myTextView.setText(spanna);
```

if you like to keep it in html you can use a `WebView` and load your html there, styling should be easier with css, I think

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks! Any idea how to add some kind of padding to the BackgroundColorSpan?

Comment: sorry I don't know if it is possible to have a real padding on spannable, the only things I can figure out is to enlarge the string with spaces xD

Comment: yeah, adding white spaces is my current solution :D It's not the most elegant solution, but it does the job! Thank you very much!

Comment: @sockeqwe, did you manage to figure out how to add padding to the spannable?

Comment: No, still use white spaces

Comment: is there some way to  get background on words only, ignoring the spaces? like ,I don't want to have  background color as `second long line` but rather as `second` `long` `line`

Comment: @anshsachdeva as far as I know you'd need to set spannables for each word, you could for instance split the string by space, then for each word create a spannable and append it to the TextView, then append a space without spannable